# Как вытянуть ответ сервера?

Tags: javascript, php

Предположим, есть таблица с сообщениями. Есть страницы с выводам всех сообщений из таблицы(СВС). Есть страница с добавлением сообщений (СДС). Возможно ли сделать, чтобы сообщение отправленное с СДС сразу же после отправки появлялись на СВС? При этом СДС и СВС могут быть на разных ПК.

Я знаю, что можно страницу СВС обновлять по таймеру, но мне скорее нужно вытаскивать с сервера ответ.

Comment: Получается вы должны не "вытаскивать" ответ, а отдавать его всем кому надо. Это значит вам необходимо смотреть в сторону использования вебсокетов. Быстро тут помочь не получится =)

Comment: а может посоветуете что то конкретное ? Видео, книжонки какие ?

Comment: Используйте long poll запросы. Т.е. создается запрос, если ответов нет, то сервер не закроет соединение, пока не появится ответ, либо закроет его по таймеру и вам тогда нужно будет просто сделать еще один запрос.

Comment: long poll запросы это же вроде как просто замена XMLHTTPRequest ?

Comment: @Kirpich643 Причем тут XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: @Kirpich643, принцип работы long poll можно понять из этой недавней статьи http://habrahabr.ru/post/160679/

Comment: А на php Это возможно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте таймер на 1 секунду, куда уж быстрее..
Но учтите, - если СДС и СВС на разных узлах, то еще нужно учесть время, необходимое http протоколу на доставку данных.  
т.е. мгновенного обновления вы все одно не добьетесь в такой постановке задачи.

Comment: А как тогда вкотнтакте сообщения работают? Они мгновенно приходят !

Comment: Таким способом, который я указал в своем комментарии выше.

Comment: Точно :) ?!